# Empty table row in while loop from query

Tags: php

I have a while loop which displays records in a table.  Works OK, but there is an extra table row at the top of the table which is empty.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <?php do { 
  $count++;
?>
    <tr bgcolor=<?php echo processRow($count); ?>>
      <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
      <td width="8%"><a href="edit_topic.php?topic_pk=<?php echo $row['topic_pk']; ?>">edit</a></td>
      <td width="12%"><a href="edit_topic.php?topic_pk=<?php echo $row['topic_pk']; ?>">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php 
   if($count == 2){
$count = 0;
}
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); 
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time the loop starts `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` is not yet executed therefore no result is being fetched.
Add `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` at the beginning of the file (before the loop) or convert the do-while loop into a while to solve the problem.

Comment: Many thanks...I got rid of the do bit and just started with the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

the `do {} while()` construct goes over the contents of the block first, before evaluating what is passed to `while`. if you write it like this, is should get rid of the empty row:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
  <? $count++; ?>
  <tr bgcolor=<?php echo processRow($count); ?>>
    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
    <td width="8%"><a href="edit_topic.php?topic_pk=<?php echo $row['topic_pk']; ?>">edit</a></td>
    <td width="12%"><a href="edit_topic.php?topic_pk=<?php echo $row['topic_pk']; ?>">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
 if($count == 2){ $count = 0; }
 endwhile; 
?>
```